# git remote show origin returns nothing

Tags: git, github

```
$ git remote show origin
```

Returns absolutely nothing. I started noticing something was weird when I tried creating and then pushing a new branch to our repo this morning. My push/pull commands just exited without saying anything.

Interestingly, the following commands show something:

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.url
https://github.com/MYCOMPANY/BLAH.git
```

Also, this is returned:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/MYCOMPANY/BLAH.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/MYCOMPANY/BLAH.git (push)
```

I tried removing origin:

```
$ git remote rm origin
```

And then re-adding it:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/MYCOMPANY/BLAH.git
```

But *remote show* still fails. Attempting to do a pull or a push just quickly exits and reports nothing.

```
 $ git fsck --full
```

Returns a bunch of dangling commits and blobs, but nothing else.

I'm not a git power user and so I feel as though I'm a bit out of my element here. I'm not sure what else to do or where to go with this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

```
$ git --version
git version 2.14.1.windows.1
```

Comment: Does `git remote show origin -n` return anything?

Comment: Yes. 

$ git remote show origin -n
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/MYCOMPANY/BLAH.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/MYCOMPANY/BLAH.git
  HEAD branch: (not queried)
  Local ref configured for 'git push' (status not queried):
    (matching) pushes to (matching)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I "got it figured out".

I uninstalled git from Windows and reinstalled it (same version). This time when I got to the options for the SSL layer, I selected the default Windows layer instead of OpenSSH. Everything started working.

No idea why or what happened.

Comment: If it happens again, some more details which could be helpful: After one of these commands which returns nothing, what does `echo $?` say? What about `GIT_TRACE=1 git remote show origin`?